# how to implement XMPP over BOSH for iOS? any known library?

Tags: ios, xcode4, xmpp, xmppframework

I know about [robbiehanson/XMPPFramework](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/) and also know that it doesn't support BOSH so please don't bother to give links to its git page.

I also know about [directi/XMPPFramwork](https://github.com/directi/xmppframework) which is a fork of robbiehanson's code and also have some implementation of BOSH, however I was not able to get it working, and the project itlself was abandoned by its authors.

I know [gloox](http://camaya.net/gloox/) supports BOSH, however since its a C++ library, I was not able to make it work with my native iOS App which is in objective-c.

Now, does anyone know about any other library for implementing XMPP over BOSH for iOS app? or if anyone can guide me the changes required to implement any of the above three libraries with BOSH support?